# CUDA: Thread and Array Allocation

Tags: cuda

I have read many times about CUDA Thread/Blocks and Array, but still don't understand point: how and when CUDA starts to run multithread for kernel function. when host calling kernel function, or inside kernel function.

For example I have this example, It just simple transpose an array. (so, it just copy value from this array to another array).

```
__global__
void transpose(float* in, float* out, uint width) {
    uint tx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    uint ty = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    out[tx * width + ty] = in[ty * width + tx];
}

int main(int args, char** vargs) {
    /*const int HEIGHT = 1024;
    const int WIDTH = 1024;
    const int SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(float);
    dim3 bDim(16, 16);
    dim3 gDim(WIDTH / bDim.x, HEIGHT / bDim.y);
    float* M = (float*)malloc(SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT * WIDTH; i++) { M[i] = i; }
    float* Md = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Md, SIZE);
    cudaMemcpy(Md,M, SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    float* Bd = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Bd, SIZE); */
    transpose<<<gDim, bDim>>>(Md, Bd, WIDTH);   // CALLING FUNCTION TRANSPOSE
    cudaMemcpy(M,Bd, SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    return 0;
}
```

(I have commented all lines that not important, just have the line calling function transpose)

I have understand all lines in function main except the line calling function `tranpose`. Does it true when I say: when we call function `transpose<<<gDim, bDim>>>(Md, Bd, WIDTH)`, CUDA will automatically assign each elements of array into one thread (and block), and when we calling "one time" tranpose, CUDA will running `gDim * bDim` times tranpose on `gDim * bDim` threads.

This point makes me feel frustrated so much, because it doesn't like multithread in java, when I use :( Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is in essence correct.

`transpose` is not a function, but a CUDA kernel. When you call a regular function, it only runs once. But when you launch a kernel a single time, CUDA will automatically run the code in the kernel many times. CUDA does this by starting many threads. Each thread runs the code in your kernel one time. The numbers inside the  tripple brackets (`<<< >>>`) is called the kernel execution configuration. It determines how many threads will be launched by CUDA and specifies some relationships between the threads.

The number of threads that will be started is calculated by multiplying up all the values in the grid and block dimensions inside the triple brackets. For instance, the number of threads will be 1,048,576 (16 * 16 * 64 * 64) in your example.

Each thread can read some variables to find out which thread it is. Those are the `blockIdx` and `threadIdx` structures at the top of the kernel. The values reflect the ones in the kernel execution configuration. So, if you run your kernel with a grid configuration of 16 x 16 (the first `dim3` in the triple brackets, you will get threads that, when they each read the `x` and `y` values in the `blockIdx` structure, will get all possible combinations of `x` and `y` between 0 and 15.

So, as you see, CUDA does not know anything about array elements or any other data structures that are specific to your kernel. It just deals with threads, thread indexes and block indexes. You then use those indexes to to determine what a given thread should do (in particular, which values in your application specific data it should work on).